# Adding button type links

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I have an Iframe embedded on my Facebook page but when i was recently editing it I have killed all the links on it..

I was wanting to add button links directly under the banner and have them centred, can someone help me put together the code to do this, I am a newbie to coding so any help is appreciated.

to find my iframe you can follow this link
https://www.facebook.com/PhotographyBok/app/190322544333196/

but the code for my iframe is currently this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>""</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<br>
<table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" style="text-align: center">
<tr> 
<td height="70" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000"> 
<img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/756/23511757696_469b593243_b.jpg"</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td width="124" rowspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000">
<a href="https://facebook.com/photographybok" target="_parent"><button>Timeline</button></a>
<a href="https://500px.com/marcus.bok" target="_parent"><button>Portfolio</button></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/PhotographyBok/app/251458316228/" target="_parent"><button>Shop Now</button></a>
<td width="459" height="118" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000" style="text-align: center">
<font color="white">"I am a self proclaimed weekend photographic warrior.
I began learning photography when I was 15, working part time in a photographic lab, developing negatives and selling camera's, I started shooting myself with a 35mm Pentax SLR that I purchased second hand in Wellington New Zealand for $10, this served me well to learn the basics about aperture, focal length and shutter speed. Now I currently shoot with a Sony A380 DSLR.
I am constantly learning, adapting and improving, comments and followers are welcome and thanked.
My favourite photographer is Ansel Adams, I take the following quote into life and into photography."</font>
</td>
<td width="153" rowspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000">
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td height="433" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000"> <font color="white">"When words become unclear, I shall focus with photographs, when images become inadequate, I shall be content with silence. - Ansel Adams"</font></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td height="44" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFC2">&copy; Marcus Bok</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jo3atpz9/

Comment: Works great thanks, but the links don't seem to link? they are dead..

Comment: That's because JsFiddle doesn't allow links to link outside of the page.

Comment: Copy-paste it into notepad, and run it locally. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jo3atpz9/

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">
  <br>
  <table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" style="text-align: center">
    <tr>
      <td height="70" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFC2">
        <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/756/23511757696_469b593243_b.jpg" </h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
          <button onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">Google</button>
            <button onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">Google</button>
          <button onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">Google</button>

                           </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td width="124 " rowspan="3 " valign="top " bgcolor="#FFFFC2 "> 
<td width="459 " height="118 " valign="top " bgcolor="#FFFFC2 " style="text-align: center ">
"insert new BIO here "
</td>
<td width="153 " rowspan="3 " valign="top " bgcolor="#FFFFC2 ">
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td height="433 " valign="top " bgcolor="#FFFFC2 "> " "When words become unclear, I shall focus with photographs, when images become inadequate, I shall be content with silence. - Ansel Adams"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="44" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFC2">&copy; Marcus Bok</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: By the way, the links don't work because jsfiddle and stackoverflow don't allow links to link away from the page in a snippet.

Comment: Yes, I've added it but still the links are broken..

        <td colspan="3">
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
          <button onClick="window.location.href='https://facebook.com/photographybok'">Timeline</button>
            <button onClick="window.location.href='https://500px.com/marcus_bok'">Portfolio</button>
          <button onClick="window.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/PhotographyBok/app/251458316228/'">Shop Now</button>

                           </div>
    </td>

Comment: Don't forget to add `//` or `http://` before `facebook.com` etc, or else the page thinks that `facebook.com` is a file faceook with extension `.com`.